# Obtaining uncertainties from an errors-in-variables machine learning algorithm

Tags: estimation, predictive-models, standard-error, prediction-interval, uncertainty

In my field, every value reported comes with a 1-sigma uncertainty value.

I'm using random forest regressors to estimate a value. All of my inputs have 1-sigma uncertainty information with them.

My random forest regressor is trained on error-free simulations, and now I want to estimate a value from real data. In a monte carlo fashion, I perturb all of my inputs within their 1-sigma errors 10,000 times and feed them to my random forest. I get out 10,000 estimates of the value.

My question: in order to obtain 1-sigma uncertainties for my predicted value, assuming the values I get out are distributed normally, is it OK to just take the mean and standard deviation of the 10,000 values?

My intuition is no: that I need to obtain prediction intervals for each of the 10,000 estimates, and somehow combine them. Is that right? And if so, how?

Comment: First of all test accuracy with OOB cross validation. If you assume the error is distributed by some function and is constant in the entire feature space, you could quantify the precision in a single number or some limits. That is not guranteed, some samples may be harder to predict. But it would work as an crude working assumption. You would need to check the error structure of the model to know